# Django rest api problem: should either include a `querylist` attribute, or override the `get_querylist()` method

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-views

This is my serializer class:

```
class JlistSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Jlist
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'news_channel', 'wiki', 'image', 'total_star', 'total_user')
```

This is my views

```
class JlistView(ObjectMultipleModelAPIView):
    queryset = Jlist.objects.all()

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        userId = self.kwargs.get('pk')
        queryset = [
            {'queryset': Jlist.objects.all(),
             'serializer_class': JlistSerializers},
            {'queryset': JStarList.objects.filter(userId=userId),
             'serializer_class': JStarList}
        ]
        return queryset
```

I am getting followiing error

```
AssertionError at /api/jlist
JlistView should either include a `querylist` attribute, or override the `get_querylist()` method.
```

I have used the same code to create api for other serializer class but getting error in creating this api.Please help me figure out what is problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined get_queryset, but it should be get_querylist. And remove queryset member too.

```
class JlistView(ObjectMultipleModelAPIView):

    def get_querylist(self, *args, **kwargs):
        userId = self.kwargs.get('pk')
        queryset = [
            {'queryset': Jlist.objects.all(),
             'serializer_class': JlistSerializers},
            {'queryset': JStarList.objects.filter(userId=userId),
             'serializer_class': JStarList}
        ]
        return queryset
```

Comment: Now getting this error: 'many' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Comment: Here is github repo. If you need any other detail https://github.com/imsaiful/backendAPI/blob/master/feed/api/views.py

Comment: Working now. Thanks. My mistake.